# Vue keep alive component when moving to other array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to keep a component alive when moving the bound item object to a different data array. Because it gets moved, the default keep-alive tag doesn't work.

I need this to improve loading time when dynamic components in my app use external libraries.

**Simplified example:** (https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/24419/)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="list in lists">
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <draggable v-model="list.items" :options="{group: 'list-items'}">
        <list-item 
           v-for="item in list.items" 
           :key="item.key" 
           :content="item.content">
        </list-item>
      </draggable>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('list-item', {
  props: {
    content: {
        required: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Mounted! ');
  },
  template: '<li>{{ content }}</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    lists: [
        {
        title: 'List 1',
        items: [
            { key: 'item1', content: 'Item 1' },
          { key: 'item2', content: 'Item 2' },
          { key: 'item3', content: 'Item 3' }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'List 2',
        items: [
            { key: 'item4', content: 'Item 4' },
          { key: 'item5', content: 'Item 5' },
          { key: 'item6', content: 'Item 6' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: I do not see any component destruction, nor any libraries. Your question is quite unclear. I also see some props, but no parent component and some Vanilla JS : document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Mounted! ')
I'm sure there is a better way to do this even if I do not know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is just a quick mockup to replicate the issue, not my actual code. When you drag items to a different list in this example, it re-renders the component, thus mounting it again. (Hence the dirty js code, to show it actually does)

Comment: It seems that the events that `draggable` exposes fire either too early or too late for what you want to do. There might be something to be done using ticks, but before I'd like to know why do you want to keep the component alive. Because if it's to preserve data, I think you can use `draggable`'s `componentData` option.

Comment: It's to preserve the DOM that gets altered by external libraries like WYSIWYG & image editors, as those can take some time to load. Data is no issue as I use Vuex in my application :)

Comment: It seems the Vue.Draggable, when dragging, adds a new component in the "drop zone" and removes the previous. It seems you'll need to modify their code to get something like you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is just one of caching expensive html build, you can do it by removing the `list-item` component from the template and building them ahead of time in `app.mounted()`.

How well this works in your real-world scenario depends on the nature of `item.content` and it's lifecycle.

```js
console.clear()
const ListItem = Vue.component('list-item', {
  props: {
    content: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Mounted! ');
  },
  template: '<li>{{ content }}</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    getHtml(content) {
      const li = new ListItem({propsData: {content}});
      li.$mount()
      return li.$el.outerHTML
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.lists.forEach(list => {
      list.items.forEach(item => {
        const cacheHtml = this.getHtml(item.content)
        Vue.set( item, 'cacheHtml', cacheHtml )
      })
    })
  },
  data: {
    lists: [
     {
       title: 'List 1',
        items: [
         { key: 'item1', content: 'Item 1' },
          { key: 'item2', content: 'Item 2' },
          { key: 'item3', content: 'Item 3' }
        ]
      },
      {
       title: 'List 2',
        items: [
         { key: 'item4', content: 'Item 4' },
          { key: 'item5', content: 'Item 5' },
          { key: 'item6', content: 'Item 6' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: move;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.6.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/15.0.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="list in lists">
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <draggable v-model="list.items" :options="{group: 'list-items'}">
        <div v-for="item in list.items" :key="item.key">
          <li v-html="item.cacheHtml"></li>   
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Reactive item.content

To keep reactivity when `item.content` changes, you will need a little more code.

- add a copy of the `item.content` to the cache
- add a method to fetch the cached html with refresh if content has changed.

(You may be able to do this a little more elegantly with a parameterized computed property).

To simulate an item.content change, I've added a setTimeout to mounted().

```js
console.clear()
const ListItem = Vue.component('list-item', {
  props: {
    content: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Mounted! ');
  },
  template: '<li>{{ content }}</li>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    getHtml(content) {
      const li = new ListItem({
        propsData: { content }
      });
      li.$mount()
      return li.$el.outerHTML
    },
    cacheHtml(item) {
      if (item.cache && item.cache.content === item.content) {
        return item.cache.html
      } else {
        const html = this.getHtml(item.content)
        const cache = {content: item.content, html} 
        Vue.set(item, 'cache', cache)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.lists.forEach(list => {
      list.items.forEach(item => {
        this.cacheHtml(item)
      })
    })
    setTimeout(() => 
      Vue.set( this.lists[0].items[0], 'content', 'changed' )
    ,2000)      
  },
  data: {
    lists: [
     {
       title: 'List 1',
        items: [
         { key: 'item1', content: 'Item 1' },
          { key: 'item2', content: 'Item 2' },
          { key: 'item3', content: 'Item 3' }
        ]
      },
      {
       title: 'List 2',
        items: [
         { key: 'item4', content: 'Item 4' },
          { key: 'item5', content: 'Item 5' },
          { key: 'item6', content: 'Item 6' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: move;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.6.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/15.0.0/vuedraggable.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="list in lists">
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <draggable v-model="list.items" :options="{group: 'list-items'}">
        <div v-for="item in list.items" :key="item.key">
          <li v-html="cacheHtml(item)"></li>   
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that loading the component outside the template is the only way to go in my case. Oh well, thanks! I'll give this a shot, and otherwise create my own take on Vue.Draggable that only changes visually, with the saved order in the data.

Comment: May not be the only way, but I've looked at vue-draggable and sortable code before and it's a bit time consuming. I currently have dragula on a Vue project - was going to adapt it to your scenario by adding an inner component (currently v-for's on `<li>`). Will post if it's any different.

Comment: Found a way to accomplish it, far from ideal but it works:

- Remove the v-model from draggable, makes the changes only visual
- Clone the initial list, use the clone for the v-for
- Catch the @sort manually, change the real list manually based on the event startIndex, endIndex, from element and to element.
- If you add or remove items from the list, do it for both lists.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea - but do you have to clone the list?

Comment: BTW, [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) does not seem to recreate the inner vue component that is dragged from one list to another.

Comment: Yes I had to clone it to prevent the reference list from altering the real list, and it's some extra work handling the draggable and doing all adding/removing twice (both lists), but I got it to work :) It'll do until a more clean solution comes up.

Answer (score 1):

i looked into your problem and i think i might found a solution, i cannot do it in js fiddle but i'll try and explain it:

in your js fiddle the mounted is hooked in your list-item component, so indeed every time that state changed (when dragging), the event is triggered.

i create a setup with a main templated component (componentX), with a mounted function, and then created a seperated list-item component

in my sample you will see the mounted twice at the start, that is normal since we have 2 lists! but then when you start to drag and drop you will not get additional mounted events

you can download the solution in a zip from:

http://www.bc3.eu/download/test-vue.zip

it is a vue cli project, so you can just `npm run dev` to start a local server

Comment: Could you re-upload it? 404 not found.

Comment: @Stanniebeer , any progress on your issue, since the bounty is ending tomorrow ?

Comment: Very safe download for sure. SUS.